# Jdbi3 - is it possible creating DB connection to postgresql which hosted on google cloud

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

I'm trying to setup a db connection using [*Jdbi3*](https://jdbi.org/). The DB we have at the moment is [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) which is hosting on google cloud.

From Jdbi3 official doc, I have tried to create the connection with:

```
jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname", "gcpUserName", "gcpPassword");
```

This is working fine only when I setup google cloud sql proxy prior.
Then I found cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory and tried with url

```
jdbc:postgresql:///dbName?cloudSqlInstance=<InstanceNmae>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<UserName>&password=<Password>
```

I've also tried to append `sslmode=disable` at the end of url.

Then I got exceptions:

```
Nov 08, 2021 4:46:20 PM com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory connect
INFO: Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [google-cloud-instance-name] via SSL socket.
Nov 08, 2021 4:46:20 PM com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory getInstance
INFO: First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
org.jdbi.v3.core.ConnectionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.open(Jdbi.java:319)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.LazyHandleSupplier.initHandle(LazyHandleSupplier.java:65)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.LazyHandleSupplier.getHandle(LazyHandleSupplier.java:53)
    at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.statement.internal.CustomizingStatementHandler.invoke(CustomizingStatementHandler.java:180)
    at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.statement.internal.SqlUpdateHandler.invoke(SqlUpdateHandler.java:32)
    at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.internal.SqlObjectInitData$1.lambda$invoke$0(SqlObjectInitData.java:132)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.Invocations.invokeWith(Invocations.java:44)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.Invocations.invokeWith(Invocations.java:26)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.LazyHandleSupplier.lambda$invokeInContext$1(LazyHandleSupplier.java:77)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.Invocations.invokeWith(Invocations.java:44)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.Invocations.invokeWith(Invocations.java:26)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.LazyHandleSupplier.invokeInContext(LazyHandleSupplier.java:76)
    at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.internal.SqlObjectInitData$1.call(SqlObjectInitData.java:138)
    at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.internal.SqlObjectInitData$1.invoke(SqlObjectInitData.java:132)
    at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectFactory.lambda$attach$2(SqlObjectFactory.java:110)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.insertNewConversation(Unknown Source)
    at nz.co.xxx.DbConversationsTest.lambda$updateConversationTagByConversationIdTest$4(DbConversationsTest.java:87)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.callWithExtension(Jdbi.java:476)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.withExtension(Jdbi.java:463)
    at nz.co.xxx.DbConversationsTest.updateConversationTagByConversationIdTest(DbConversationsTest.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:286)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.lambda$create$0(Jdbi.java:114)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.open(Jdbi.java:303)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(CoreSocketFactory.java:376)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.getInstance(CoreSocketFactory.java:140)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect(CoreSocketFactory.java:252)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:76)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:226)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:125)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:97)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(CoreSocketFactory.java:374)
    ... 82 more
```

For some reason, I can't enable SSL for IAM authentication at the moment. So, is it possible from disable SSL mode from Jdbi3 side? Or is there a way from gcp side. Any inputs are welcome, Thank you.

Comment: I understand that the Application Default Credentials seems to be not available. Correct me if my understanding is incorrect. 
They are available for running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable. GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. For more information refer to [ADC](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials)

Comment: On a VM running in GCE they would be available (through the metadata server),
If not running in GCE, one must set the environmental variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to a file that holds the downloaded credentials. For more information refer to [Create Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#create_service_account)

Comment: What we currently doing is we setup gcloud on local env, using cloud_sql_proxy to connect the DB, sorry I forgot to mention this in the question.